# Invalid string or buffer Length Exception in Java EE web application

Tags: java, sql-server, exception, jdbc

I am quite new to Java programming and I am currently developing my first web application using the MVC Architecture. But I am encountering quite a lot of problems with my Application and I don't have a clue why they are occurring. For instance I have the following code in my JSP page:

```
                Connection connection = null;
                PreparedStatement statement = null;
                ResultSet rs = null;
                String QueryString="";
                String stuid="";
                try {
                        QueryString = "SELECT Student_ID, Student_F_Name, Student_L_Name, Student_NIC, Student_Address, Student_DOB, Student_Email, Student_Gender, Course_Name, Batch_Name, Student_username, Student_password FROM Student WHERE Student_ID = ?";
                        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver").newInstance();
                        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("Jdbc:Odbc:UniversityDSN");
                        statement=connection.prepareStatement(QueryString);
                        stuid = session.getAttribute("studentid").toString();
                        statement.setString(1, stuid);
                        rs = statement.executeQuery();
```

At times this code works Perfectly, but after a while, this code stops working and it provides an error as:

> INFO: SQLException:[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Invalid string or buffer length

But If I amend the above code as following:

```
String QueryString = "SELECT Student_ID, Student_F_Name, Student_L_Name, Student_NIC, Student_Address, Student_DOB, Student_Email, Student_Gender, Course_Name, Batch_Name, Student_username, Student_password FROM Student WHERE Student_ID = ?";
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver").newInstance();
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("Jdbc:Odbc:UniversityDSN");
PreparedStatement statement=connection.prepareStatement(QueryString);
String stuid = session.getAttribute("studentid").toString();
statement.setString(1, stuid);
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();
```

it will start working again. But in a while, this code will again stop working giving the same exception and I have to amend it as the way it was earlier.
But in both these times the code works perfectly if I debug it.
This is quite annoying as I have to waste a lot of my time amending my code and it happens in JSP Pages, or Servlets or in the Bean classes I use.
I would really appreciate if someone can suggest me what I maybe doing wrong and how can I avoid this issue?

Comment: MVC is a pattern not an architecture.

Comment: Thank you for the information. As I said, I am still a student and quite new to Java and MVC. I will keep your information in mind. Albeit I would really appreciate if you can provide any suggestions for my problem.
Thank you again :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, java odbc driver is not very good for webservers and multi-threaded environments. I really think it is related to your bug.

It lost db connections references. And there is nothing you could do. The only way is to use the JDBC driver for MS SQL, a better driver for web environments.

> INFO: SQLException:[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Invalid string or buffer length

It is sometimes linked to upgrades of the db server too.
Because the version of the java odbc driver must match with the db server version...

Comment: Thanks for your reply mate! I will try with the JDBC for MS SQL. But it's weird that most my classmates use the Java ODBC driver but they aren't facing this problem.
So I suppose it might have something to do with the upgrades of the DB server? In that case what would you suggest me to do? Is there any way of upgrading the Java Odbc driver?

Comment: In programming, sometimes the masses doing the things bad don't see the bugs while they put theirs programs in production envs. Some people are lucky: they are facing these problems at earlier stages. Look at your db version, and the driver version provided with must match any matrix compatibility you could find on MS SQL webpages. Same applies to odbc driver.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this problem while using an external connector to the oracle database. The problem here is ODBC driver. I was using Oracle 11G and had created a DSN in the source. The JDBC-ODBC driver which was needed for Oracle 11G was ojdbc5.jar. I changed the driver and the error was gone. This error primarily has to do with 64 bit processes.